# Конвертация DateTime со стринга

Tags: c#, datetime

**Конвертирую "05-Feb-18 5:44:00 AM"**

```
date = DateTime.ParseExact(reader["DateTime"].ToString(), "dd-MMM-yy H:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

> Exception: System.FormatException: 'String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.'

Как решить вопрос?

Comment: А что такое `reader`?

Comment: SQLiteDataReader. Из него он достанет тот стринг, что и я написал

Comment: Напишите перед этой строкой `var x = reader["DateTime"];`, поставьте брекпоинт и посмотрите в отладчике тип переменной `x`

Comment: Ошибка уже не в парсе) Сделал как написали, улетел тот же ексепшн

Comment: Это уже очень странно. Падает точно на этой строчке? Столбец в запросе точно называется `DateTime`?

Comment: Да. Проверил уже 100 раз и название столбца и его номер и отделил строчку отдельно. Падает на ней

Comment: не по теме ошибки, но в комбинации с tt часы должны форматироваться как h, а не H

Comment: с h давно уже заметил и исправил. Роли не играет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перепробовал кучу способов. Помогло такое:

```
date = DateTime.ParseExact(reader.GetString(3), "dd-MMM-yy h:mm:ss tt", null)
```

Почему-то сразу парсить не хотело.

Answer (score 1):

Вы делаете неправильно, вы получаете из БД дату, преобразуете ее в строку, а потом парсите обратно в дату.

Просто воспользуйтесь методом `GetDateTime` своего экземпляра `SQLiteDataReader`:

```
date = reader.GetDateTime(номер столбца);
```

или попробуйте кастовать результат индексатора в дату:

```
date = (DateTime)reader["DateTime"];
```

Comment: Попробовал оба способа. Ошибка та же

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте этот вариант, у меня работает(в MSQL поле Date формата DateTime, _sqlCon - ваше sql соединение):

```
var selectCommand = _sqlCon.CreateCommand();
selectCommand.CommandText = "SELECT Date FROM [dbo].[time];";
SqlDataReader reader = selectCommand.ExecuteReader();
reader.Read();
var dateSQL = reader.GetDateTime(0);
```

Ну или, если хотите туда-сюда парсить(из datetime в string, потом обратно) проверьте ещё раз строку, которую вы достаете из базы данных.
Так как подобный тест проходит без ошибок:

```
string dateString = "05-Feb-18 5:44:00 AM";
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "dd-MMM-yy H:mm:ss tt", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: @AndriyKlym если представленный вами способ работает, значит в базе данных поле имеет формат Text, а не DateTime, иначе вылетала бы ошибка.